# How to update Highcharts with React JS via input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to create a Highcharts chart with input fields that allows the user to customise their own color preferences. However I am relatively new to using React JS. I am passing the values from the input fields and appending them to the chart options and want to update the chart when a submit button is clicked. I have tried using setState() and also redraw() from the React api but I am having no luck with it. I have been getting this error when running it on the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (VM111:125)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ VM111:125
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
    $('#submit').click(function () {     
           this.chart.setState(function () {
            return {
                chart:{
                        backgroundColor: '' + $('#backgroundColorSetting').val() //sets chart background 
                },
                series: [{
                        color: '' + $('#colorSetting').val(),           //sets the color of Line
                    name: $('#xaxis').val()                                 //sets name of X-Axis
                }],
                yAxis:{
                        text: $('#yaxis').val()                             //sets name of Y-Axis
                }

            }
            });
    });
var Chart = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {

      if (this.props.modules) {
        this.props.modules.forEach(function(module) {
          module(Highcharts);
        });
      }

      this.chart = new Highcharts[this.props.type || "Chart"](
        this.props.container,
        this.props.options
      );
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
      this.chart.destroy();
    },

     render: function() {
      return React.createElement('div', {
        id: this.props.container
      });
    }
  }),
  categories= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  data= [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
element = React.createElement(Chart, {
  container: 'chart',
  options: {

    title: {
        text: 'Inverted Chart'
    },
    chart: {
            inverted: true,
            polar: false
            },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Subtitle1'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: data,
        lineColor:'#f7eac8'
        //showInLegend: false
    }]
  }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('react-inverted'));
```

Comment: Can you add a link to your example? Or paste all the code?

Comment: Hi I have updated with all the code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use jQuery if you use React. Forms can be handled with React components. I recommend to read about [forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) (especially controlled components) in React docs. I will use an uncontrolled component.

Change render method to render form:

```
render: function() {
     return React.createElement('div', null,
       React.createElement('div', {
         id: this.props.container
       }),
       React.createElement('form', {
           onSubmit: this.onSubmit
         },
         React.createElement('input', {
           ref: input => this.colorInput = input,
           placeholder: 'Type red, black or blue'
         }),
         React.createElement('input', {
           type: 'submit'
         })
       )
     );
   }
```

and define a submit handler which will update the axis via [Axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update)

```
onSubmit: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var color = this.colorInput.value;
     if (['red', 'black', 'blue'].includes(color)) {
       this.chart.xAxis[0].update({
         lineColor: color
       });
     }
   },
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/mec4huyw/

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, this has worked for me, I was trying too much to do it as jQuery would. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fiddle throws console error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined"